# Vue custom v-model value doesn't update the value after getting it from axios get request

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

I have a component called "TextInput":

```
<template>
    <q-input
        v-model="content"
        @input="handleInput"
        color="secondary"
        :float-label="floatLabel" />
</template>

<script>
    import { QInput, QField } from "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm";
    export default {
        props: ['floatLabel', 'value'],
        data () {
            return {
                content: this.value
            }
        },
        components: {
            'q-field': QField,
            'q-input': QInput,
        },
        methods: {
            handleInput(e) {
                this.$emit('input', this.content)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I used this component in another component:

```
<template>
    <card card-title = "Edit Skill">
        <img slot="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <form class="clearfix" slot="form">
            <bim-text v-model="skill.name" :floatLabel="input_label"></bim-text>
            <q-btn
                @click="edit"
                icon="save"
                size="14px"
                color="secondary"
                label="Save" />
        </form>
    </card>
</template>

<script>
    import { QBtn } from "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm";
    import { Card, TextInput } from "../../base";
    import router from '../../../routes/routes';
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                skill: {
                    name: ''
                },
                input_label: 'Skill Name'
            }
        },
        components: {
            'card': Card,
            'bim-text': TextInput,
            'q-btn': QBtn
        },
        methods: {
            edit: function(){
                axios.patch('/api/skills/'+this.id, {
                    name: this.skill.name,
                }, { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '.concat(localStorage.getItem('token')) } })
                .then(response => {
                alert('success');
                router.push({ name: "IndexSkills"});
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('dd');
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get("/api/skills/"+this.id, { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '.concat(localStorage.getItem('token')) } })
                .then(response => {
                    this.skill = response.data.data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    alert('error')
                });
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .q-btn{
        float: right;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see, I created an skill object with empty property called name and I made an axios request to get the specified object using its id. In then function of the axios request skill should be updated but what happened was that the v-model still empty.

What would be the problem here? and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only assign `v-model` value (`value` property) to your `content` variable on initialization (`data()` method, which is only called on component initialization). You have no code that can react to `value` (`v-model`) change, that would update the `content` variable.

You should create a watch for `value`, and then set `this.content = this.value` again.

PS: Also, try instead of this

```
this.skill = response.data.data;
```

do this

```
this.skill.name = response.data.data.name;
```

Comment: when I set the skill variable to null not to be an object having an attribute called name. it worked but first of all raised an error says the skill.name is not defined  but it appears in the text component after that. 
I didn't notice the error unless I opened the console.

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan did you try `this.$set(this.skill, 'name', data.nam)`? (or `Vue.$set()`).

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Could you please paste a fiddle with your code that demonstrates your unwanted behaviour?

Comment: Did you also create a watch in your component, as I suggested?

Comment: I did that in TextInput component which is the base component i used and then it works.
I still have a question: why when i put skill as null it works without watcher but when i use skill as object I must use watcher to get the change.

Comment: My best guess is that, if you pass an object as a property, you pass it by **reference**. If you modify that object's property - vue is not notified, but the object property's value of course is changed. If you set it to `null`, you change object's value (and destroying the reference) and (by changing object's value, not object's property value) Vue is notified and has to re-render view which probably makes it work by accident.

Comment: So, as a rule of thumb, if you want to make a **dynamic** two-way binding, you always have to use watch.